# HTML type drop down in excel

Tags: excel

Is there any way to have a dropdown in excel that will show a value instead of the text e.g. First option is Option 1 but value is 1

I am trying to find an easy for users to select an item without having to know the ID of that item in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

First set the **ListFillRange property** to a multi-column range (for example, "A1:B3").  Then set the **ColumnWidths property** to something like "50;0", which will make the second column invisible.  And finally, set the **BoundColumn property** to 2.

The list will display Option1, Option2, Option3.  And if you query it's value (ComboBox1.Value), it will return the value associated with the selected option (1, 2 or 3).

Comment: Is this possible in Excel 2003?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not.

But you may use your `Options` as `IDs` in the database as long as none of them are duplicates (which I think should be the case, or your users will not be able to distinguish them).