# Excel dropdown list add ids with display item

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have a problem regarding Excel 2010/2007. I need dropdown having Display item and Ids like Html/asp.net dropdown. My data is like that 1- apple, 3 - orange, 10 - Egg .

These Ids are the values of the Display text. How can I achieve that and last this list is also implementing on all rows.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to set the ComboBox's **ListFillRange** to a multi-colunm range containing data and IDs and then set the **BoundColumn** property the column containing the IDs, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465576/html-type-drop-down-in-excel).